# typing with latex

Tags: errors

I've working on this for about two hours, but still can't find any wrong with it. This is what I type in:

```
\documentclas [a4papter, 12pt] {article}
\begin{document}

find \(lim_{x \to 3^+}\)\( frac{2x}{x-3}\) and \(lim_{x\to 3^-}\)\(frac{2x}{x-3}\)

\end{document}
```

Could anyone told me that what's the wrong with it? Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the error. Also, you seem to be missing a number of \s and $s, and you've misspelled `documentclass` and `a4paper`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As fluffy said, it is `\documentclass`, and also `\lim` and `\frac`, i.e., with backslashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had `\documentclas` (a final "s" was missing) and this will cause an error. Also, you had `a4papter` and it should be `a4paper` (this will only cause a warning, but it is still an incorrection and should be taken care of).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

find  \(\lim_{x \to 3^+}\frac{2x}{x-3} \) and \( \lim_{x\to 3^-}\frac{2x}{x-3} \)

find  
\[
\lim_{x \to 3^+}\frac{2x}{x-3} \text{ and } \lim_{x\to 3^-}\frac{2x}{x-3}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that you have `\lim` to appropriately typeset limits (correct font and spacing) and that you need `\frac` to typeset fractions. In my example I also show both the in-line and the displayed forms of your expression.

As long as you are in a math expression, you don't have to close math mode and reopen it, so you can simply say

```
\( \lim_{x \to 3^+}\frac{2x}{x-3} \)
```

instead of

```
\( \lim_{x \to 3^+} \)\( \frac{2x}{x-3} \)
```

Comment: There's also `a4papter` and you should have seen the relative message on the terminal. ;-)